# jQuery Animate Large Image Starts Choppy

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to animate a large image using jQuery. The begining of the animation starts off a little choppy and after that it works fine. I've expereinced this in Chrome and am looking for a possible solution to fix this.

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/Jakowenko/mFExK/1/

```
#scroll {
    background: url("http://wakpaper.com/large/Linux_wallpapers_341.jpg") repeat;
    width: 7800px;
    height: 560px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

<div id="scroll"></div>

animateStart("#scroll");

function animateStart(holder) {

    $(holder).stop().animate({
        left:"-3910px"
        }, 60000, function() {
        //animateEnd(holder);
    });

}
```

Comment: Would you be opposed to using CSS transitions instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me it's not choppy at all but it might be an easing issue. jQuery default easing is swing, setting it to linear may fix your problem

http://jsfiddle.net/mFExK/2/

Comment: Thanks, that solved my issue. As soon as I can accept I will.